# Using request.FILES in GAE ModelForm

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a django form using djangoforms.ModelForm. One of the required fields I have is a FileField. I've been trying to figure out how to pass the uploaded file to the form.

I've been trying to use something like:

```
def post(self):
    form = StudentForm(data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<appengine_dir>/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/<project_dir>/app/handlers/students.py", line 22, in post
    form = StudentForm(data=self.request.POST, files=self.request.FILES)
  File "/<appengine_dir>/google_appengine/lib/webob/webob/__init__.py", line 500, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: FILES
```

I have specifically specified django 1.2, and I have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set in my form. Is there anything else that I am missing?

The closest question I could find was [Uploading files to App Engine using webapp and Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052673/uploading-files-to-app-engine-using-webapp-and-django-forms).

In my case, I know the field name in advance and would be OK using a similar method as was posted. However, I was not able to figure it out or make it work.

Your help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we adapt the answer to the other question you mentioned, that would look like this (not tested):

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

upload = self.request.params['field_name']
django_files_dict = {'field_name': SimpleUploadedFile(upload.filename,
                                                      upload.file.read())}
form = StudentForm(data=self.request.POST, files=django_files_dict)
```

Does it work? If not what error message are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've tried something like this before. This time I get a different error message: http://pastebin.com/BF4gK1e8